# Sharepoint 2013 Manage Service Applications - Missing PowerPoint Automation Services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, service-application, powerpoint-automation

We just did a fresh SharePoint 2013 farm installation and want to manually configure the service applications used - we are *not using* the **Farm Configuration Wizard**.

The issue we are facing is that [**PowerPoint Automation Services**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179894%28v=office.15%29.aspx) does not appear in *Central Administration->Application Management->Manage Service Applications->New* menu dropdown - but *Word Automation Services* and other service applications do.

How do you create a new **PowerPoint Automation Service** application and proxy for Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that some SharePoint service applications do not appear under the *Application Management->Manage Service Applications->New* dropdown menu because Microsoft chose not to add them.

In order to create them - you cannot use CA, you must rely on PowerShell as [discussed in this MS TechNet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4e47323c-ff12-4287-baee-403d3362d810/no-option-to-install-powerpoint-conversion-service-or-workflow-service-applications).

#### PowerShell to Create PowerPoint Service Application and Proxy

```
New-SPPowerPointConversionServiceApplication -Name "PowerPoint Automation Service" -ApplicationPool "SharePoint Web Services Default"
New-SPPowerPointConversionServiceApplicationProxy -Name "PowerPoint Automation Service" -ServiceApplication "PowerPoint Automation Service"
```